# Web Bluetooth with Password

Tags: javascript, web-bluetooth, btle

Is it possible to connect to a bluetooth device that supports Bluetooth 4.0 LE but has a password.

I can connect to the device from an iphone and print (which only supports BTLE) but when I try and connect from chrome (OSX) / web-bluetooth it does not prompt me for a password.  I can return a device using:

```js
navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({name: 'PRINTER'})
```

but when I try to connect using

```js
device.gatt.connect()
```

the promise never resolves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web-Bluetooth does not support Bluetooth 4.0's Secure Simple Pairing (SSP) / Pin-Codes.

I resolved the issue by disabling the pin-code and posting a request for SSP in the bluetooth CG.

Answer (score 1):

Can you get `device.gatt.connect()` to resolve on Android?

Your best bet to solve your issue would be to file a Chromium bug by following instructions at https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/file-web-bluetooth-bugs

Comment: Hi Fracois, It was the pin code that was breaking the connection.  I've added a ticket to the CG.